# How can I make sure my JUnit test method's specific cleanup always runs?

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have a JUnit test class that has two test methods:

```
@Test
public void test1() {
    // Setup: Create foo1.m
    // Exercise
    // Tear Down: Delete foo1.m
}

@Test
public void test2() {
    // Setup: Create foo2.m
    // Exercise
    // Tear Down: Delete foo2.m
}
```

For each method, I would like to make sure that, if the Exercise section fails for any reason, the Tear Down will still run. Note that the Setup and Tear Down code for both test methods are different, so I don't think I can use JUnit's @Before and @After annotations to do what I want.

I could put TRY-CATCH blocks into each test method:

```
@Test
public void test2() {
    // Setup: Create foo2.m
    try {
        // Exercise
    } finally {
        // Tear Down: Delete foo2.m
    }
}
```

but that seems ugly. Is there a way to make sure the test-method-specific tear down code in each test method is executed, without using a TRY-CATCH block?

Comment: If you don't want common \@Before and \@After then each test method has its own code and that code and its variables is limited in scope to that method. I'm not sure what you'd need to "tear down" if that's the case; the GC is going to do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

I found a better solution, so I include here, the original answer can be found below. I think JUnit 4 rules can be used here:

```
class PrepareFile implements org.junit.rules.TestRule {

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface FileName {
        String value() default "";
    }

    @Override
    public Statement apply(final Statement statement, final Description description) {
        return new Statement() {

            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                String fileName = description.getAnnotation(FileName.class).value();
                File file = new File(fileName);
                try { 
                    file.createNewFile();
                    statement.evaluate();
                } finally {
                    file.delete();
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Using it in the test:

```
@Rule
public PrepareFile prepareFile = new PrepareFile();

@Test
@PrepareFile.FileName("foo1.m")
public void test1() {
    // Exercise
}

@Test
@PrepareFile.FileName("foo2.m")
public void test2() {
    // Exercise
}
```

**Here comes my original answer:**

You may try to use the `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` annotations.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() {
    // Setup1: Create foo1.m
    // Setup2: Create foo2.m
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDown() {
    // Tear Down1: Delete foo1.m
    // Tear Down2: Delete foo2.m
}

@Test
public void test1() {
    // Exercise
}

@Test
public void test2() {
     // Exercise
}
```

This way you can setup and tear down all test cases once and the framework ensures that `teadDown()` is called in case of errors as well.

Answer (score 2):

If the setup and teardown are different, you are essentially cramming two different test fixtures into a single file. The sensible answer is to put them in separate files and use the normal annotations. If they have anything in common separate that out into a common abstract class.

Adding multiple setups in the same file can easily result in a situation where it's not clear which instance members are used in which tests, so that maintaining the tests becomes a lot harder than it needs to be.